# Pandas Apply/Lambda returning dataframe and not single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

New to Python and Pandas, so please bear with me here.

I have created a dataframe with 10 rows, with a column called 'Distance' and I want to calculate a new column (TotalCost) with `apply` and a lambda funtion that I have created. Snippet below of the function

```
def TotalCost(Distance, m, c):
    return m * df.Distance + c
```

where `Distance` is the column in the dataframe `df`, while `m` and `c` are just constants that I declare earlier in the main code.

I then try to apply it in the following manner:

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: TotalCost(row['Distance'], m, c), axis=1)
```

but when running this, I keep getting a dataframe as an output, instead of a single row.

EDIT: Adding in an example of input and desired output,

```
Input: df = {Distance: '1','2','3'}
```

if we assume m and c equal 10,
then the output of applying the function should be

```
df['TotalCost'] = 20,30,40
```

I will post the error below this, but what am I missing here? As far as I understand, my syntax is correct. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

The error message:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1
```

Comment: Please remember to format your code before submitting any question

Comment: It would be easier if you posted example of your input with desired output. Please take a look at how to provide [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is a more memory-efficient and cleaner way:

```
df.eval('total_cost = @m * Distance + @c', inplace=True)
```

Update: I also sometimes stick to assign,

```
df = df.assign(total_cost=lambda x: TotalCost(x['Distance'], m, c))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give these both a try

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda in `apply` should process only one row. BTW, `apply` return only calculated columns, not whole dataframe

```
def TotalCost(Distance,m,c): return m * Distance + c

df['TotalCost'] = df.apply(lambda row: TotalCost(row['Distance'],m,c),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apply function will basically pass one row at a time to your lambda function and then returns a copy of your data frame with the edited or changed values

> Finally it returns a modified copy of dataframe constructed with rows returned by lambda functions, instead of altering the original dataframe.

have a look at this link it should help you gain more insight
https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-apply-a-function-to-each-row-column-in-dataframe/

```
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def star(x,m,c):
    return x*m+c
vals=[(1,2,4),
     (3,4,5),
    (5,6,6) ]
df=pd.DataFrame(vals,columns=('one','two','three'))
res=df.apply(star,axis=0,args=[2,3])
```

Initial DataFrame

```
one two three
0   1   2   4
1   3   4   5
2   5   6   6
```

After applying the function you should get this stored in res

```
    one two three
0   5   7   11
1   9   11  13
2   13  15  15
```